# What's the word for a tiny sharp piece of wood under your skin?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When you work with crude wood (or iron) without gloves, you easily *get injured with a tiny sharp piece of wood* which remains under your skin and needs to be removed.

What is the word for this small piece of wood used in that particular case? I've found several words in the dictionary but without the collocation: *splint*, *splinter*, *sliver*.

And what is the whole phrase for the injury? Something like *to get a splint*?

Comment: If they're wood, they *are* "splinters". I'm sure there's a different word specifically for ***swarf*** (from metalwork) splinters, but if I can't call it to mind probably most others can't either. So they'd still talk about "splinters of metal".

Comment: Why -1? Please explain *how* my question doesn't meet the site's standard.

Comment: This link may help: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter

Comment: @ Honza: I didn't actually vote one way or the other. If all you're asking is "What do you call a small piece of wood broken off under your skin", I'm inclined to think the question is Off Topic General Reference. I posted my comment to give you a chance of editing the question before I *do* closevote it for that reason (unless you're actually asking something else that *is* on topic).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm new to this forum, so I ask this question because I'm trying to figure out the way this site operates. Can you help me understand how a question that fits within the meaning of a predefined tag on this site—in this case "single-word-requests"—can be considered off-topic?

Comment: @ Honza: Wll, you'd already got as far as identifying *splint, splinter, sliver* as possible candidates. Obviously you missed Merriam-Webster's example usage [*I got a splinter in my finger.*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/splinter). It's a judgement call, but I'd say checking example usages should be the next step for you. If your knowledge of English doesn't stretch that far perhaps you should be asking questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In Norfolk we call it a *shivver*.

Comment: @WS2: So [Eric Fowler says](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shiver+in+my+finger%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (*shiver*, not *shivver*). But there are only three instances of *shiver in my finger* in Google Books - they're all in "Norfolk dialect guides", and the other two are from the 1800s. Not too common compared to 1710 instances of [splinter in my finger](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22splinter+in+my+finger%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: @Lacey See [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3878/74434) [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3618/74434) and [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/74434) for more info....and I'm still trying to figure it out myself ;)

Comment: A [splint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_(medicine)) is apt to be understand as some rigid item used to stabilize a broken or severly sprained limb.  A finger split might be used in the case of an injured finger, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Since there is no accepted convention on Norfolk spellings to my knowledge, I give *shivver* phonetic treatment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that you can use *splinter* regardless of the material. In Merriam-Webster's Unabridged Dictionary online (subscription required), the example sentence for *splinter* in the meaning you intend references metal.

> **splin·ter** 
>   noun \ˈsplintə(r)\ 
> plural -s 
> 1 a (1) :  a thin often jagged
>   or needlelike piece split or rent off lengthwise :  **sliver, chip,
>   fragment**
>              
>  gloves … protect a worker from sharp steel splinters —
>   Michael Cawley
>   the steering wheel … was knocked into splinters by an
>   enemy shot — Edward Breck  
> (2) :  a small jagged or needlelike
>   particle or flash 
> flying splinters of ice — William Beebe
>   irradiated for a moment now and then by splinters shooting through
>   the darkness — E. K. Brown

And I think *sliver* is an acceptable synonym for *splinter* in your use. Here's the definition for *sliver* from the same source:

> **sliv·er** 
> noun \ˈslivə(r)\ 
> plural -s 
> 1 a : 
>   a long slender piece cut or torn off :  **splinter** 
> a piece of apple pie
>   with a sliver of cheese on top — F. C. Othman 
> was building up the
>   fire with split logs and pine slivers — William Faulkner

Neither of these words refer to the action of getting a fragment stick under the skin, so in formal use you would have to specify: "Last time Bob tried whittling, a splinter stuck in his finger, and he couldn't get it out for days."  But when the use is informal, I don't think it's a problem to imply the action: "Ow! I just got a splinter!"

Comment: To me, a sliver and a splinter are basically the same object. But once it gets stuck under your skin an sits there, annoying the bejeezus out of you for ages, the synonymy stops: it can only be a splinter, then. I just cannot hear “I have a sliver in my finger” as normal in my head. M-W has the example, “I got a sliver of wood stuck in my finger”, which I think works because it has both ‘sliver _of wood_’ (referring to the thing-as-a-thing itself) and ‘stuck’; but I’ve never heard anyone say, “Ouch! I just got a sliver!”.

Comment: @Lacey "splinter" and "sliver" are not synonyms. A sliver is any thin piece of any material, not necessarily sharp or even rigid, and there's no "default" material for a sliver: note that both the examples you quote specify the material, whereas "a splinter" is inferred to be a sharp sliver of wood unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Although less common, I have definitely heard people say, "I just got a sliver"—perhaps it is a regional use.

Answer (score 10):

It's called a *splinter* in the case of wood. "I've got a splinter in my bum from sliding down the bannister". [Splints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_splints) are something else.

That's because wood can break apart (splinter) into sharp bits. In the case of metal, I'd call it a metal cutting, a chip, a shaving, a sliver, or a piece of [swarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarf).

In the case of glass, I'd call it a sliver or a shard.

Comment: You can also call the metal thing a 'metal splinter'.

Comment: @Mitch It looks better to me with scare quotes around "splinter".

Answer (score 5):

There is an uncommon but a more specific word: ***skelf.***

> a splinter of wood, esp when embedded accidentally in the skin
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skelf</sub>

It is from Scottish English and used as a slang mainly. You can encounter in literature too.

Also, ***spell*** and ***spelk*** is used as a splinter of wood but they are more of a dialectal word and uncommon.

**Note:** This would be a supplementary answer to Sphero Pefhany's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/185942/74434). He already mentioned the most common usage in his answer.